# Printing all string elements in list except for one in Python

Tags: python, list

So I'm making a scheduling program that randomly schedules NHL teams. I have a mini list of teams from the Atlantic Division:

```
atl_div = ["BOS", "BUF", "DET", "FLA"]
```

When a user enters a team abbreviation, they get the elements printed to them, minus the team in the list, for example if I entered `BUF`, the user would get back:

```
BOS
DET
FLA
```

I tried

```
input_team = input("Enter a team abbrev.:")

if input_team == "BUF":
   print(atl_div[~0])
```

but that won't work, since `~` is used on numbers and not lists.

I have to admit I'm a bit of a novice programmer, so I apologize if it sounds that way in my question. We all start somewhere :)

Thank you for any help and feel free to ask for more details if necessary!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input_team = input('Enter a team abbrev.:')
print('\n'.join([team for team in atl_div if team != input_team]))
```

EDIT: Updated print formatting

Comment: Note that this will print a string representation of a list, which is different than the output format expected by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `list` comprehension will produce a new `list` without the undesired element:

```
print(*[team for team in atl_div if team != input_team], sep="\n")
```

That makes a new `list` temporarily with all elements except those equal to `input_team`. The `*` unpacks it as sequential positional arguments to `print`, and `sep="\n"` tells `print` to put a newline between each element when printing. If you want to permanently remove the element in question from the `list`, you can instead do:

```
atl_div.remove(input_team)
print(*atl_div, sep="\n")
```

Note that the behavior will differ a bit if there isn't exactly one entry matching `input_team`; `remove` will throw an exception if no matching element exists, and it will only remove one copy if there is more than one instance of the value in the `list`. The `list` comprehension will silently remove all copies of the value, and doesn't care if there weren't any to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Two easy ways you can do this:

The simplest way would be to go one by one through the list, and print any one that is not the string you are explicitly looking not to pick.

```
for team in atl_div:
    if input_team != team:
        print(team)
```

An arguably more Pythonic way of doing the same thing, although not as efficient (with a small list like this efficiency is not as important) you can do a list comprehension, and make a list like. This way, you're going to make a new list, which doesn't have the team you're looking for.

```
included_teams = [x for x in atl_div if x != input_team]
```

You can then print out that list, element by element:

```
for team in included_teams:
    print(included_teams)
```

This can be simplified to the following, perhaps slightly less readable version of that same problem:

```
for team in [x for x in atl_div if x != input_team]:
    print(team)
```

In either of these solutions, you can be more forgiving, and apply string transforms like `.upper()` to the `input_team` to allow it so that a user who enters `buf` would still get the expected list, `BOS, DET, FLA`.

With the first answer, this can be done like so:

```
for team in atl_div:
    if input_team.upper() != team:
        print(team)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pandas you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
aa = pd.Series(["BOS", "BUF", "DET", "FLA"]) 
aa[aa != 'BOS'].tolist()
# ['BUF', 'DET', 'FLA']
```